# Writing from a file in an order after multiple string matching

Tags: python, string, match

My question is, is there a way to write to a file in CSV format using the data from another file(data file) after multiple string matching from the first column of the data file? Also please let me know if there is an efficient way to do this.

ex :

**data_file**

Jan 01 01 02
Feb 01 04 02
Feb 01 01 03
Feb 01 01 03
Jan 01 01 02
Jan 01 01 02

The way I want to arrange to a new file is

Jan xx xx xx
Jan xx xx xx
Jan xx xx xx
Feb xx xx xx
Feb xx xx xx
Feb xx xx xx

So far I tried this and only the Jan part gets written,

```
string1 = 'Jan'
string2 = 'Feb'
with open(file1, "r") as Input:
    total_lines = Input.readline()
    with open(file2,"w+") as Output:
        Output.write(total_lines+'\n')
        for line in Input:
            if string1 in line:
                write_data_1 = line.split('   ')
                for i in write_data_1:
                    Output.write(i)
        for line in Input:
            if string2 in line:
                write_data_2 = line.split('   ')
                for j in write_data_2:
                    Output.write(j)
```

Comment: You need to seek back to the beginning of the file before the second loop.

Comment: With `file.seek(0)`

Comment: Why are you splitting the line? Why not just `Output.write(line)`?

Comment: because in the actual file the numbers(xx) aren't as ordered as in this example. So I thought to use split(). Is that wrong?

Comment: But you're writing them in the same order in the `for` loop, so how does that solve the problem? Anyway, it has nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comment. I will get rid of that. I appreciate your help